# Making an executable from ruby files using Ocra, LoadError?

Tags: ruby, executable, require, ocra

I'm trying to make an executable from a couple ruby files on Windows, so I installed Ocra. I thought I understood the process of how Ocra works, but can't seem to get the executable working correctly. The problem I am having arises with "requiring" other ruby files.

The ruby program by itself compiles correctly and functions how I want it to, and Ocra seems to create a working executable, however, when I attempt to run the executable, I get the following error:

*/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require': cannot load such file -- MainMenuDialog.rb (LoadError)*

My main program is called 'JobManager.rb' and it is creating a new MainMenuDialog object, therefore I include MainMenuDialog.rb in the top of the file as such:

```
$: << File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../lib")
# Other requires here
require("MainMenuDialog.rb")
```

Again, the program compiles and runs perfectly fine by itself (including the require statements), and when I run the command *ocra JobManager.rb* it successfully runs the programs, checks for dependencies, and creates the executable. I just can't run the executable because of the "LoadError" described above.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Did you try to replace your code with a `require_relative`? (Needs ruby >= 1.9)

Comment: That did the trick. I thought the "$: << ..." line allowed me to use "require" instead of "require_relative" but I guess it wasn't working how I thought it was. Thanks!

Comment: I made an answer from my comment, so you can confirm that the question is answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ruby >= 1.9 you may try `require_relative`.

Explanation: ocra stores all files in its own subdirectories.

If you manipulate the load pathes ($:) you can't be sure, what ocra uses during execution.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old and answered, but I wanted to include this little nugget I found in [Ocra documentation](https://github.com/larsch/ocra#running-your-application), because the correct answer here did not resolve my issue:

> OCRA does not set up the include path. Use `$:.unshift
>   File.dirname($0)` at the start of your script if you need to 'require'
>   additional source files from the same directory as your main script.